# What is the highest known trophic level for a consumer?

Tags: food-web

Or rather, what's the longest known food chain between a producer and an apex predator?

I've found a few similar questions and answers online, but none of the questions clarified some of the nuances of the question meaning all of the answers I've found are rather vague (e.g: ['about 10'](https://www.reddit.com/r/biology/comments/dvdai6/comment/f7bzkkq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) or [a more specific value without a specific chain](https://www.mmnp-journal.org/articles/mmnp/pdf/2008/04/mmnp20084p131.pdf), ["we don't know"](https://arts-literature.blurtit.com/177128/what-is-the-longest-food-chain-in-the-animal-world), ['it depends'](https://arts-literature.blurtit.com/177128/what-is-the-longest-food-chain-in-the-animal-world), ['in the ocean'](https://www.reddit.com/r/biology/comments/dvdai6/comment/f7bzkkq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) or 'infinitely long') or [just random guesses](https://arts-literature.blurtit.com/177128/what-is-the-longest-food-chain-in-the-animal-world) [(x2)](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-longest-food-chain-in-nature-where-one-organism-consumes-the-next-for-example-mackerel-tuna-or-shark).

You might be able to consider the food chain of cannibalistic species or two species which consume each other to be infinitely long, so I'll assert that a food chain can not contain the same species twice. Also don't consider food chains that are only *theoretically possible*, I'm interested in what food chains actually exist and actively occur between widespread species. This also means not including species which eat just about everything, unless the species being eaten is one of their primary prey.

There probably isn't a definitive answer to this or a way to prove that one food chain is the longest, but I'm just interested in how long a food chain can get.

Comment: Hi and Welcome! You may not know that this site requires **evidence** of [prior research](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (quote and link to source/s) in an attempt to answer your own question (this is a Q&A site, but one with slightly higher expectations.) For example, have you searched for the role of environment on food chains, etc.? If so, what have you found? Showing evidence or research greatly increases your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: you might have an easier time by making the trophic level version of the question the title, the food chain one all but unanswerable.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I wasn't sure how to site my sources properly, since StackExchange seems to just treat Markdown references as links but I used some sources multiple times or had multiple sources for one point, but I've done my best

Comment: That was an excellent edit to include sources. Since you did your part, I'll try to find out. I fully expect, though, not to find one definitive/reliable longest food chain length. The more complex the ecosystem, the more likely to be more "steps" in the food chain (E.g. a desert is less complex than a salt marsh.) I'll avoid the ridiculous or artificial. (E.g. coyotes > ospreys > ship rats)

Comment: OK, I did try. The common answer is "unknown", one reason being that food webs are seasonal, another is that the same species can be lower or higher in the food chain depending on size, population, etc., and oof!!! The most complex ecosystem on earth is the tropical rainforest, but I found more trophic levels in the ocean. But none were fixed; they change and are interconnected. Ugh. I'm sorry; I would have liked to have given a better answer.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Don't worry! I was fully anticipating there to not be a definitive answer thanks to the many variables involved. And you've clearly done far more research than me haha. Since it seems most of the variables relate in some way to time, maybe it be possible to identify a worst-case and best-case scenario?

Comment: I just decided I don't know enough to say much of anything. I read a number of papers, but I'm still kinda flummoxed. See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S245231001830060X) for an example of how complex oceanic food webs are. You should see the tables, some with hundreds of superimposed webs.